# Truststore in AWS IoT java client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, x509certificate, aws-iot

In the documentation for the python client for AWS Iot it is very straight forward how to specify the truststore but how do I do the same with the java client?

```
myMQTTClient.configureCredentials("YOUR/ROOT/CA/PATH", "PRIVATE/KEY/PATH", "CERTIFICATE/PATH")
```

Sources:

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Iot Java SDK has rootCA pre encoded in the keystore so it does not need customer to provide that."
Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247938